# How to pass information between scenes with JavaFX

Tags: java, class, javafx

Assume there are 2 scenes, first one is a Login page, and second is a Game page. User enters his username and password in a Login page (there is a Player table in the database which has id, username and password columns). I want to access username and password information in the Game page, because I will save the score of current player to the database. I saw some solutions with FXML which has `FXMLLoader()`, but I don't use FXML. Any solutions and ideas for that problem will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way you would pass information between any 2 classes. Them being scenes or whatever doesn't change anything.

Comment: @m0skit0 I still cannot pass value of username and password. For example, I write a function in Login which returns "userNameField.getText()", but when I call this function in Game that is not work. When I try it with simple void function in Login which prints something, I can call that function in Game, but as I said for that specific "userNameField.getText()" value that is not work.

Comment: Please provide your code and a more detailed description of your problem, i.e. what you mean by "does not work".

Answer (score -1):

I have my app doing this fine, but i can not share the exact code with you because work policies, but what you need is to set up right your setters and getters to make that posible, I mean in your second scene you need this for example...

```
private final Text username = new Text();
public Text getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}
public YOURCLASSNAME setUsername(final string username){
    this.username.setText(username);
    return this;
}
```

I hope it helps you...